# SQL Server Soundex() and Difference() to Compare a Columns observations to Itself

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, difference, soundex

I am looking for some assistance in using `Soundex()` and `Difference()` in SQL Server with the goal of comparing one observation in a column to another observation in that same column.

Here is some context of how the data looks. All of these street addresses are intended to represent the same place, but with human error changing a small portion so it isn't exactly the same:

| Street Address | zip | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1440 thisisastreetaddress ave | 12345 | OH |
| 1440 thisismystreetaddress st | 12345 | OH |
| 1440 thisisthestreetaddress rd | 12345 | OH |

The goal would be to use `Soundex()` and `Difference()` to group addresses that are similar to each other. Problem is, the table has over 2 million customers so the solution cannot operate on massive amounts of CPU. The end product doesn't have to be pretty, I don't mind sorting manually  (which I've realized is what may need to happen to an extent), but I would appreciate the script grouping them for me.

Let me know if its possible with `soundex()` and `difference()` and, if its not with those two, any other functions or ways you may go about solving this. Also may be important to include that it can be a multiple software solution as the team and myself know python, R, power BI, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Given large amount of data, I would copy the table to avoid locking up main production table when processing data. 2. Assuming that the street address is stored as one/two lines (and not in its component form) I would combine the lines together and strip out any address parts that soundex does not like e.g. house numbers. 3. Add a column to store `SOUNDEX` value. 4. Run your `UPDATE` statement to calc `SOUNDEX` values in batches of a few thousand records at a time in a loop. This way you can see how long it would take to run and quality check results of the first few batches.

Comment: Add indexes to state and ZIP code columns as they would be the primary grouping columns. You only have to compare `SOUNDEX` values to each other within these groups. A PK ID column is a must have for this as well.